# Java - Converting data from a DataOutputStream to a File where DataOutputStream size is unknown

Tags: java, tcp, inputstream, file-transfer

This is a simplified version of my program.
I have a Server.java file where I read in "b.txt" into a byte array and then write it to the DataOutputStream.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4000);
            Socket s = ss.accept();

            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            byte[] byteArray = new byte[32];

            File tempFile = new File("Files/b.txt");
            FileInputStream fis = new 

            FileInputStream(tempFile);

            fis.read(byteArray);
            fis.close();

            dout.write(byteArray);
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();

            s.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //handle exceptions
        }
    } 
}
```

In Client.java I read the DataInputStream into a byteArray. Then, I create a FileOutputStream. In the commented out code fos.write(byteArray), this writes to the file, however since the actual file may not be exactly 32 bytes I am left with a corrupt file since the remaining bytes just get filled with random data (or whatever happens).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 4000);
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

            byte[] byteArray = new byte[32];

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Downloaded/testfile.txt");
            //fos.write(byteArray);

            int count;
            while ((count = din.read(byteArray)) > 0) {
                fos.write(byteArray, 0, count);
            }

            fos.close();
            din.close();

            s.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //handle exceptions
        }
    }
}
```

So I looked up how to fix this and a lot of places told me to do the code I have inside the while loop: while ((count = din.read... etc.

However when I try this, testfile.txt is blank and contains 0 bytes. Am I missing something big here? I have tried sending in the correct amount of bytes from the server, however this doesn't change anything.

I would like to be able to transfer any file type, so it is important that I am able to transfer the correct amount of bytes without corrupting the data by having bytes "hanging over". Thank you.

Comment: Did you remember to close your streams?

Comment: @Kayaman yes I just edited my code and it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Well edit your question to reflect your real code, because currently your client doesn't close the streams, and it seems to do an extra `din.read(byteArray)`.

Comment: I've edited it, and thanks for pointing it out. However when I remove the extra din.read(byteArray) now I get the original problem where I have overhanging bytes. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: You're ignoring how many bytes `Server` actually read at `fis.read(byteArray)`. You need to write only the amount of bytes that were read, instead of the whole 32 byte buffer. Just like in the client.

Comment: If your only goal is to copy a file to an OutputStream, use [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,java.io.OutputStream%29).